# Dual citizen born in England wishes to move back after 47 years in US

Tags: dual-citizenship

I was born in England to American parents.I have dual citizenship.I have lived in the US for 47 years.I now wish to move back to England. My child passports have been lost. What do I need to do?

Comment: Do you have a birth certificate?

Answer (score 4):

You will need some documentary proof of your British nationality.  According to the UK's citizenship checker, you can prove that you are British by showing that you were born in the UK before 1983.  (See https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen/y/before-1-january-1983/yes.)  Therefore, as implied by user102008, a birth certificate will do.  Most likely, though, you'll want to get a passport.

If your birth certificate is also lost, you can find out how to get a new copy at https://www.gov.uk/order-copy-birth-death-marriage-certificate.

To apply for a UK passport while you are in the US, visit https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports.  There, you can choose "replacing a lost or stolen passport"; you will also find links to the application guidance and to a list of supporting documents you will need to submit.

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions. I have the birth certificate issued to my parents by the American consulate in London; but not the long form British birth certificate. I plan to order one. Since posting this I have led into applying for my British passport. I am concerned that they require my parents passport numbers. My mother is deceased and my father is elderly and in poor health. I'm not sure how I will retrieve these numbers. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SuzanneBoyer Do they need that information even though you previously held a UK passport?